# I registered the type but still get error "gob: type not registered for interface:"

Tags: go, encoding, gob

I can't seem to figure out why a custom struct is not Registered with encoding/gob

This error happens when I attempt to save the Gorilla session:

```
could not save session: securecookie: error - caused by: securecookie: error - caused by: gob: type not registered for interface: []*baseball.Athlete
```

Here is the struct

```
type Athlete struct {
    AuthID      string
    DisplayName string
    Email       string
    Coach       string
}
```

I'm Registering the struct with init() fuction

```
gob.Register(&baseball.Athlete{})
```

In an auth function I attempt to save a session containing the entity.

```
athlete := make([]*baseball.Athlete, 0)
_, err = q.GetAll(ctx, &athlete)

if len(athlete) == 0 {

    athlete := &baseball.Athlete{
        AuthID:      id_token.Sub, // I'm using id_token.sub which is unigue to Google, not sure if other Oauth2 providers have equivalent
        Email:       id_token.Email,
    }

    _, err := datastore.Put(ctx, datastore.NewIncompleteKey(ctx, "Athlete", nil), athlete)
    if err != nil {
        return appErrorf(err, "authgo: new Athlete put failed: %v", err)
    }
}

oauthFlowSession.Values[currentAthleteKey] = athlete

log.Printf("$#$#$#$#$#$2 in auth.go athlete is type: %T", athlete)
if err := oauthFlowSession.Save(r, w); err != nil {
    return appErrorf(err, "could not save session: %v", err)
}
```

Here is the server log of the error:

```
2019/07/24 21:05:56 athlete is type []*baseball.Athlete
2019/07/24 21:05:56 Handler error: status code: 500, message: could not save session: securecookie: error - caused by: securecookie: error - caused by: gob: type not registered for interface: []*baseball.Athlete, underlying err: securecookie.MultiError{securecookie.cookieError{typ:1, msg:"", cause:securecookie.cookieError{typ:1, msg:"", cause:(*errors.errorString)(0xc4201f8a60)}}}
```

Different Variations:
gob.Register([]*baseball.Athlete) ==>  error: type []*baseball.Athlete is not an expression

Side question, how would you say "[]*baseball.Athlete" ?

I'm guessing, "slice that is a pointer to struct baseball.Athlete"

Comment: Register the type reported in the error message: `gob.Register([]*baseball.Athlete{})`

Comment: gob.Register([]*baseball.Athlete)   throws error: type []*baseball.Athlete is not an expression

Comment: You are missing the {}.  Copy and paste from my comment.

Comment: To your side note at the end - I'd call it "slice *of* pointer to Athlete". "Slice *that is a pointer* to Athlete" implies the slice is a pointer, which it isn't, it's a slice.